# Call Async function in Signal Handler, Asyncio

Tags: python, discord.py, python-asyncio

I am making a Discord bot using discord.py and sometimes the script I use to run it needs to close out the bot. When I close it out without using signal handlers there is a lot of errors about a loop not closing, so I added a signal handler (using the code below) and inside I need to call `client.close()` and `client.logout()`, but the problem is those are async functions and thus require me to await them, but I can't await the functions since the signal handler can't be an async function.

Here is the code:

```py
def handler():
    print("Logging out of Discord Bot")
    client.logout()
    client.close()
    sys.exit()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

    for signame in ('SIGINT', 'SIGTERM'):
        client.loop.add_signal_handler(getattr(signal, signame),
                                lambda: asyncio.ensure_future(handler()))
```

Is there a way to either logout properly using the signal handler, or at least just silence the warnings and errors from inside the code so no errors are printed in the console.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your approach is on the right track - since `add_signal_handler` expects an ordinary function and not an async function, you do need to call `ensure_future` (or its cousin `create_task`) to submit an async function to run in the event loop. The next step is to actually make `handler` async, and `await` the coroutines it invokes:

```
async def handler():
    print("Logging out of Discord Bot")
    await client.logout()
    await client.close()
    asyncio.get_event_loop().stop()
```

Note that I changed `sys.exit()` to explicit stopping of the event loop, because asyncio doesn't react well to `sys.exit()` being invoked from the middle of a callback (it catches the `SystemExit` exception and complains of an unretrieved exception).

Since I don't have discord to test, I tested it by changing the logout and close with a sleep:

```
import asyncio, signal

async def handler():
    print("sleeping a bit...")
    await asyncio.sleep(0.2)
    print('exiting')
    asyncio.get_event_loop().stop()

def setup():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    for signame in ('SIGINT', 'SIGTERM'):
        loop.add_signal_handler(getattr(signal, signame),
                                lambda: asyncio.create_task(handler()))

setup()
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

If you are starting the event loop using something other than `run_forever`, such as `asyncio.run(some_function())`, then you will need to replace `loop.stop()` with the code that sets whatever event the main coroutine awaits. For example, if it awaits `server.serve_forever()` on a server, then you'd pass the server object to `handler` and call `server.close()`, and so on.

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply. This got rid of most of the errors. The one problem I still have is the message that shows up: "Unclosed Client Session. Client Session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at xxxxxx>." Do you know what could cause this? I feel like it is a discord.py thing but I really couldnt find any documentation on closing a bot in this manner.

Comment: @JaredCohen It's an aiohttp thing. If you're using aiohttp somewhere in your program, you should pass the session to the handler and await `session.close()` as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, as described in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#set-signal-handlers-for-sigint-and-sigterm), registering handlers for signals using the `loop.add_signal_handler()` only works on Unix systems. On Windows, the example above would raise `NotImplementedError`. I'm wondering whether or not there is a workaround/something equivalent to this that would work on Windows as well.